# R: Creating a data frame with column names corresponding to row names from a variable

Tags: r

SO, I have a dataframe (let's say df1) whose column names correspond the characters in the cells (observations) of a separate variable (var1), but in a different order. df1 also has some extra columns that do not correspond to anything in var1. I want to create another dataframe (df2) whose columns match the names in var1 IN THE SAME ORDER and only contains those columns.

I assume that an R loop is the right way to go with this, but I am pretty new to R and I am unsure of how to proceed.

To recap, `df1` might look like this (BUT MUCH LARGER):

[image]
and var1 looks like this:

```
 V1  
1 frog  
2 sample  
3 mouse
```

I want the output (`df2`) to look like this:

```
         frog          sample              mouse  
1   1.7580004       ARHGEF10L         0.79790041  
2  -2.3078847           HIF3A        -1.13418473  
3  -0.4556149           RNF17        -0.45561492  
4  -0.1363775           RNF10         0.03217751  
5  -1.2339385           RNF11        -0.31903849  
6  -0.7853651           RNF13        -0.19546513
```

Again, I realize that at this scale I could just take the vectors and stack them next to each other in a data frame as I please. But the real data is MUCH larger, so I need to automate it. Any advice is much appreciated

Comment: Please use dput to show few lines of dataset instead of images

Comment: The solution provided by @akrun gave you exactly what you asked for, what was wrong about it?

Comment: I was unclear about the purpose of the script. I want it to read var1 from top to bottom and return the corresponding columns from df1 in exactly that order, with the output being another dataframe df2. The data above is just sample data. The real var1 vector has dozens of cells, and the real df1 has about a hundred columns. So, I can't manually input the column names that I require in the order I require them. I need for example a loop that takes each name from var1 and returns the column (vector) that matches that name (from the header) in df1, and smacks it on the end of df2 in order.

Comment: Why not just use indexing (with `[`) as akrun suggested?

Comment: Matthew - my bad on the cut and pasting. I will fix it. Thanks for catching that.

Comment: What is wrong with @akruns solution?? Can you please explan?

Comment: I can no longer view akrun's suggestions at the moment. But as a side question which might help me in the meantime, how do you transpose a row to a column? (i.e., the row inputs would be the column titles/headers). I am what they might call in some circles a "newb"...so please bear with me!! Thanks

Comment: @akrun, please undelete your answer.

Comment: It worked - Thank you @akrun. And thanks to David Arenburg and Matthew Lundberg for clarifying

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the "V1" column in "var1" to "subset" the dataset "df1"

```
df2 <-  df1[var1$V1]
```

#### data

```
var1 <- structure(list(V1 = c("frog", "sample", "mouse")), 
.Names = "V1", class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3"))

set.seed(25)
df1 <- data.frame(sample=c('ARHGEF10L', 'H1F3A', 'RNF17', 'RNF10',
 'RNF11', 'RNF13'), mouse=rnorm(6), human=rnorm(6), frog=rnorm(6),
 squirrel=rnorm(6))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem is, the purpose of this script is to not have to write out all of the column names, and to instead get their names and order from var1. The real data has dozens of columns.

Comment: @HenriW Where did I write all the column names in `df2<- df1[var1$V1]`?  You showed the `df2` output to contain three columns that are the elements in `V1` from `var1` dataset.

Comment: Woa! I'm doing to double check but I think it worked.

Comment: reviewing the data, it appears that either (1) the right number of columns were added but in incorrect order or (2) the right number of columns were added and drawn from random places in df1, possibly the first x columns. Could you think of any reason that this might happen/what a fix would be? Thanks so much.

Comment: @HenriW  Based on the examples I created, it is working in the way as expected.  If you find any troubles, please do update your post with the `dput` output (just like the one in my post, `dput(droplevels(head(dataset)))`)  of the examples that show the anomaly.

Comment: Nevermind. I had hyphens in var1 so it wouldn't process them for column headers. Thanks anyways.

Comment: OK...so if possible (I am totally new to this) could you show me how to do that same subset as above, but assuming that var1 has hyphens? (so does df1 in the column names of course). Thank you

Comment: @HenriW Can you show exactly the names of the objects and the variables?

Comment: Values in var1: TCGA-AA-A01Z-01, TCGA-AA-3517-11, TCGA-CM-4743-01, TCGA-3L-AA1B-01, TCGA-CA-5256-01, TCGA-G4-6626-01
Column names in df1:  TCGA-DM-A28E-01, TCGA-D5-6928-01, TCGA-A6-A566-01, TCGA-AA-3517-11, TCGA-CM-4743-01, TCGA-CK-5915-01 TCGA-CA-5256-01, TCGA-AA-A01Z-01, TCGA-3L-AA1B-01,TCGA-G4-6626-01

Comment: @HenriW And what are the column names of `df1`

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally posted comment before finishing. Column names are in new edit.

Comment: @HenriW DId you created the dataset similar to  `df1 <- data.frame("TCGA-AA-3517-11"=1:5, check.names=FALSE)`?

Comment: @HenriW If I create the two datasets `dat <- data.frame("TCGC-AA-3517-11"=1:5, "TCGA-CM-4743-01"=6:10, "TCGA-AA-3517-11"=11:15, check.names=FALSE); var1 <- data.frame(V1=c('TCGA-CM-4743-01', 'TCGA-AA-3517-11'), stringsAsFactors=FALSE);  dat[var1$V1]`, I get the result as expected

Comment: yes. Though I also successfully wrote my subset using check.names = TRUE, after converting the hyphens to periods in var1. Only thing is, I need to have hyphens in the final product. If there is a way to convert all periods in a dataframe header to hyphens, then that totally solves my problem. Either way is great thanks.

Comment: @HenriW Please note that I used `check.names=FALSE`.  For the `.` in your column names, you could change by `colnames(dat) <- gsub('[.]', '-', colnames(dat))`

Comment: Very helpful. Finally all finished!